# Mongodb $mergeObjects use variable attribute as object key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoid

I'm currently writing an aggregation and have an array named `tags` of complex objects like: `{name: 'tag1'}`.

I want to make sure that the array only contains unique `tags`.

```
    {
        $addFields: {
            uniqueTags: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$tags",
                    initialValue: {},
                    in: {$mergeObjects: {"$$this.name": "$$this"}}
        }}
    }},
```

The above code fails because I am using `$$this.name`as the object key.  If i were to change it to something else, `5` for example, the aggregation works perfecting.

Comment: Could you show sample documents and the output you want

Answer (score 0):

`$addToSet` works for nested objects.